# String Addition / Subtraction Function

Tags: vb.net, string, eval, addition, scriptcontrol

This was a possibility in VB Script by using a script control with the eval function. For example

```
ScriptControl1.Eval("(10+1.5)") 'Returns 11.5
```

Is there a way to do this in Vb.Net? The alternative would be to simply split up the string and verify if it is an addition or a subtracting and work from there. I was just wondering if there's already a built in function that I'm not yet aware of.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to add a COM reference to Microsoft Script control like so:
[image]

Then I just declare my new variable as a Script  Control.

```
Dim ScriptControl1 As New MSScriptControl.ScriptControl()
ScriptControl1.Eval("(10+1.5)") ' Returns 11.5
```

### Note*

Make sure your Target CPU is at x86! I would receive a COMException if i had it set to Any CPU.